# How to integrate the following

Tags: integration, problem-solving

How would you go about to solve it for **b)**? I tried by parts but its way to long to be the most efficient way to go about.

> Calculate the multiple integrals $\displaystyle\iint_{D} f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$ where $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $D\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is given by:
>
> $a)$ $f(x,y) = x^{3} + 3x^{2}y+y^{3} \text{ and } D = [0,2]\times [0,1]$.
>
> $b)$ $f(x,y) = \displaystyle\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \text{ and } D = [1,2]\times [1,2]$.

Comment: Polar coordinates?

Comment: Wolfram has your answer. (Do y integration first) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx%2F(x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2),%7By,1,2%7D%5D

Comment: I am not interested in the answer rather in the most efficient method to use. I did using y as constant first but than it is super long to integrate

Comment: Just the y integral is the easy part. The second part is more of a bear. It is not a simple integral. What makes you think there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** integrate wrt $y$.

$$I=\int_1^2\int_1^2\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx=\int_1^2\left[\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)\right]_1^2\,dx=\int_1^2\arctan\left(\frac2x\right)-\arctan\left(\frac1x \right)\,dx$$

**Step 2:** integrate each term by parts.

$$\int_1^2\arctan\left(\frac2x\right)\,dx=\left[x\arctan\frac2x\right]_1^2+\int_1^2\frac{x}{4+x^2}\,dx\\=2\cdot\frac\pi4-\arctan 2+\log8-{\log{5}}$$

$$\int_1^2\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)\,dx=\left[x\arctan\frac1x\right]_1^2+\int_1^2\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\=-\frac\pi4+2\arctan \frac12+\frac12\log5-\frac12{\log{2}}$$
So the **overall solution** is $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{I=\frac{3\pi}{4}-\arctan 2-2\arctan \left(\frac12\right)+\log\left(\frac85\right)-\frac12\log\left(\frac52\right)}$$

Comment: Doing it with $x$ first leads to $$\log \left(\frac{4+y^2}{1+y^2}\right)$$ which I am not sure how to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

We could use polar coordinates to simplify $f(x,y)$  but also we have to use it in the square.

$$f(r, \theta ) = cos (\theta)/r$$

For the region, we can define

$$r=2sec( \theta),   -\pi/4<\theta < \pi/4 $$

$$r=2csc(  \theta),  \pi/4<\theta <3/ \pi $$

$$r= sec( \theta),   3\pi/4<\theta < 5\pi/4$$

$$r= csc( \theta),   5\pi/4<\theta < 7\pi/4 $$